# Starting a Blazor Server with Crontab on reboot on RPi

Tags: bash, cron, raspberry-pi, blazor-server-side, cron-task

I have a Blazor Server running on my Raspberry-Pi and am trying to start it every reboot via crontab (as you may have figured).
I have a script which starts the Blazor Server

```
#!/bin/bash
echo >> /home/.../log
echo >> /home/.../log
date >> /home/.../log
cd /var/.../bin/Release/net8.0/linux-arm/publish/
/var/.../bin/Release/net8.0/linux-arm/publish/published >> /home/.../log &
echo >> /home/.../log
echo >> /home/.../log
```

and I have a crontab service to start this script on reboot

```
@reboot sleep 120 && /home/.../start.sh
```

When I run the `start.sh` file noramlly, it executes just fine, and the Blazor Server starts. However, when the script is started via `crontab -e` (or `sudo crontab -e`), the Blazor Server doesn't start. the `log` file only has the date outputted.

Attempted Remedies:

*"The network isn't ready when the script is run, and therefore doesn't run"*

The `crontab` task has a 2 minute delay before the script runs; and I ssh in **before** it has run - the network is 100% ready when the script is run.

*"Script is run using ~/ location instead of full path"*

The script uses the full path (whether it be /home/... or /var/...).

*"The script is not executable"*

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 ... ... 367 Month Day N:OW start.sh`
The crontab service is run as sudo; and the published Blazor Server file is also `wrx` for all users

Comment: anything in system logs (eg, /var/log/syslog) indicating a potential issue? does a simple `@reboot echo "running crontab @ reboot entry" >> /home/.../log 2>&1` generate any entries in /home/.../log? does `man 5 crontab` mention @reboot (ie, does your cron support @reboot)?

Comment: `man 5 crontab` does mention @reboot; cron and syslog both say task started; and without putting your entry into cron, the log just outputs the date, and the two "empty"s (`'echo '`). No info about the blazor server even being run but with errors - just nothing. And yes, the script work just fine - even when run as `su`... but not with `sudo` in front (error: .NET location: not found). is this the same error?

Comment: In any case, `cron` is inherently and unfixably broken and should be avoided. [Better options are readily available](https://www.thedigitalpictureframe.com/ultimate-guide-systemd-autostart-scripts-raspberry-pi/) (and have been, for 10+ years now).

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek soz I only got back to this now, made a systemd task according to provided link, still only date in log file :( Checked service log file says `active (exited)`; and output says `.NET location: Not found.`. again, running the script form ssh is perfectly fine - no issues. running `whereis dotnet` says `dotnet: /usr/local/bin/dotnet`